# What alternative when I get: "Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed"

Tags: swift, first-class-functions

When I do this:

```
struct Test {
  var value: Int = 0

  mutating func increment(amount: Int) { value += amount }
  mutating func decrement(amount: Int) { value -= amount }

  func apply(technique: (Int) -> ()) {
    print("Before:\(value)")
    technique(2)
    print("After:\(value)")
  }

  mutating func main() {
    apply(technique: increment) //Error: "Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed"
  }

}
```

I get this error message:
I've read this:
[Partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488316/partial-application-of-mutating-method-is-not-allowed)
and can see the problem but can't work out what the alternative code should be?

My key requirement is that I want set up a series of "techniques" such as increment and decrement and then "apply" them with a simple call.

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: This is a struct. Note that value types are copied. Just consider what piece of memory would be the one mutated.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan.  And if I change to a class (and drop 'mutating' where it occurs) then all is fine.  I'd rather stick with s struct if I can but still can't see how I would change my code to work with a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to accept an `inout Test` in `technique`. Also you should make `apply` `mutating`, because it undoubtedly changes the state of `Test`.

```
mutating func apply(technique: (inout Test, Int) -> ()) {
    print("Before:\(value)")
    technique(&self, 2) // this is "kind of" analogous to "self.technique(2)"
    print("After:\(value)")
}

mutating func main() {
    apply(technique: {
        $0.increment(amount: $1)
    })
}
```